# Julia: how stable are serialize() / deserialize()

Tags: serialization, julia

I am considering the use of serialize() and deserialize() for all of my data i/o due to their convenience. I do not, however, want to be stuck with unreadable files on a Julia update.

How stable are serialize() and deserialize()? Should they work between updates of 0.3? Can I expect safe behavior if I stick to basic types like arrays of Float64?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a better question for the [julia-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to store data you might depend on being able to read in the future, you should not use a format that will incorporate breaking changes if/when someone finds it useful. As far as I understand the default serialization format is for network communications, so it is designed for maximum performance.

There is also the [HDF5.jl](https://github.com/timholy/HDF5.jl) package that uses a documented format and a common library that has wrappers for different languages.

Comment: the problem with HDF5 is that there are types that you can't serialize. For example, I just got the following error when trying to serialize a GLM model: "MethodError: no method matching write(::HDF5File, ::String, ::StatsModels.DataFrameRegressionModel)"

Answer (score 5):

I believe the official answer here is, "people will try not to break the serialization format, but you shouldn't depend upon on it."

Comment: You can treat the combination of the official docs with Jeff's comment on this diff as a citation. http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/ + https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/bb67ff25e2799b27d10877692f74bae66ccc0270